# lirc Error: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0

Tags: raspbian, lirc

I've been trying to setup a IR transmitter for ages. I'm running a RasPi B with the latest Raspbian lite.

I installed `lirc` and added `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=23,gpio_in_pin=22,gpio_in_pull=up,debug=1` to my `config.txt`.

I really don't care about the receiver, I only need to be able to transmit signals.

If I try to `irsend` I get a `hardware does not support sending` error.

Here is the dump from the lirc service status. I've been trying to solve the error but with no luck.

```
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd[578]: lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Warning: Failed to initialize hardware
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd[578]: lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Notice: lircd(default) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Info: Cannot configure the rc device for /dev/lirc0
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Error: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: default_init(): No such file or directory
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Warning: Failed to initialize hardware
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
May 26 00:48:39 raspberrypi lircd-0.9.4c[578]: Notice: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
```

Comment: What have you connected, and where?

Comment: NOTE in latest update to Raspbian "Name:   lirc-rpi
Info:   This overlay has been deprecated and removed - see gpio-ir"

Comment: @Milliways yeah, I read about that, however i can't find any clear docs, especially as I need a transmitter and not a receiver. Any link to docs/tutorials would be appreciated

Comment: I connected an IR led to pin 23 with a transistor, tho I don't understand what kind of hardware error I could be getting