# LIRC won't setup the device

Tags: raspbian, gpio, raspbian-stretch, driver, lirc

Very new to this low-level driver stuff, so many places to make mistakes.
Basically I'm trying to get an IR transmitter with lirc. I have a IR led to pin 23 with a transistor, however there's nothing in `/dev/lirc` or `/dev/lirc0`

I installed lirc with `apt-get install lirc`,

then added `dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=23,gpio_in_pin=22` to `config.txt` and changed `lirc_options.conf` to

```
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0
```

However, there's nothing in `/dev`, and if I try to send with `irsend` I get `hardware does not support sending`. The system status for lircd shows this error:

```
Error: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
```

I'm using a RPi 3B running Raspbian Stretch with `Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219` firmware.

I don't know what other command dump you might need so just comment and I'll add to the question

NOTE: I was reading about `gpio-ir` however that seems to be receiver only. Any link to any library with IR transmission would be appreciated too.

Comment: For some time I have worked with **lirc**. It's not about a transmitter, so it doesn't match your problem. But maybe it's worth a tick to get a new idea: [Raspberry Pi 3 not lirc not running/working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81885/79866).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lirc Error: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98987/lirc-error-could-not-get-file-information-for-dev-lirc0)

Answer (score 3):

So apparently the only problem is that the `lirc` drivers are outdated and not present in newer versions of raspbian. Just change that to the new `gpio-ir-tx` driver and all will work fine. Also note the syntax for the pins changed slightly. I.e, this is what you need in your `/boot/config.txt`

```
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23
```